# How to add SQL query parameters into service report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a query with the parameters @startDate and @endDate. They are not apart of the table columns/fields. Is there a way to show the startdate and enddate in the report using the business intelligence development studio? My main goal is to show the dates for which the data I am returning occurred. The query is shown below:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_GetSystemAvailability]
    @startDate = N'12/31/2013',
    @endDate = N'1/9/2014'
```

Comment: how these paramters are being passed to the Stored Procedure ?? I guess report Parameters ???

Comment: @M.Ali Yes they are being passed through the report.  Using the query designer option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a text box some where on your report and add an expression something like

```
="Start Date: " &  Format(Parameters!startDate.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")  & " and End Date: " 
  &  Format(Parameters!EndDate.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Assuming `StartDate` and `EndDate` are the names of your report parameters.

Comment: Sorry I believe I worded it wrong. I dont have any report parameters. The parameters I want to add are from the actual query. I specified a startdate and enddate in sql server to obtain my data.

Comment: The 12/31/2013 and 1/9/2014 in the example for the start and end date is something I did before doing anything with the report service.

Comment: Well if you are passing the value to your store procedure then you need to hard code the value into the above expression. just replace  `Parameters!startDate.Value` with your hardcoded values.

Comment: so there is no way to do this without hardcoding? because the dates are going to be changing from time to time

Comment: Since you are hardcoding the value only you would know what value you have passed, unless you make these parameters OUTPUT and used them in you report. to show the passed values.